# replacing a character in pandas cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b","c"])
df.loc[1] = [1,2,3]
df.loc[2] = ["123.12", "3455,435",0]
df.loc[3] = [23.2, 55.5,0.1]
df.loc[4] = ["1,3","3,5","7.8"]
```

and I want to replace all the commas (",") with dot ("."), in a way that the result looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b","c"])
df.loc[1] = [1,2,3]
df.loc[2] = ["123.12", "3455.435",0]
df.loc[3] = [23.2, 55.5,0.1]
df.loc[4] = ["1.3","3.5","7.8"]
```

How can I do that? So far, I've used pandas *replace* function, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True` for substrings replacement:

```
df = df.replace(',','.', regex=True)
print (df)
        a         b    c
1       1         2    3
2  123.12  3455.435    0
3    23.2      55.5  0.1
4     1.3       3.5  7.8
```